# Widgets and Commands created by loop

Tags: python, tkinter

It is two weeks now that I full-time look for a solution to a relevant problem: How to create Commands within dynamic loops? The subject is simple (to image it I took food elements): to initiate the programme, I have a number of packs to determine (for instance 5, then press Enter). Then thanks to created Comboboxes, for each case, specify whether it is fruits, vegetable, or other. The aim of each Combobox is to create again a Widget proper to value executed. The problem is that when `Bind` is executed, loops works for the whole sequence and duplicate anterior widget. the problem may be resolved by adding an instruction at line 48 such as:

```
if 'Selection'.get() == self.Combo_Food_liste[i]:
```

but I look for 'Selection' meaning Object I cannot reach it! Or if you have a better Idea, I would be very pleased to know it!

Thank you!!

```
from ttk    import *
from Tkinter import *



class Postproc:
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.variable_Title_Frame = []
        self.variable_Title =[]
        self.Combo_Food_Select=[]
        self.Combo_Food_stock=[]
        self.Combo_Food_liste=[]
        self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select={}
        self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock={}
        self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste={}
        self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry={}
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title(title)
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.Closes)

        Frame1 = Frame(self.parent,borderwidth=.5,relief=GROOVE)
        Frame1.pack(side=LEFT,padx=1,pady=1)
        ### Define the number of packs then press 'Enter'
        self.variables_Title_number=IntVar()        
        self.Field_Ouputs = Entry(Frame1, textvariable=self.variables_Title_number, bg ='bisque', fg='maroon')
        self.Field_Ouputs.pack(side=LEFT,padx=1,pady=1)
        self.Field_Ouputs.bind("<Return>", self.Launch_Outputs)
    def Closes(self, event=None):
        self.parent.destroy()
    def Launch_Outputs(self, event=None):
        self.Nombr = self.variables_Title_number.get()
        self.Create_Outputs(self.Nombr)
    def Create_Outputs(self, Nombr):
        #### Define for each pack the kind of food
        for i in range (0,Nombr):            
         self.variable_Title_Frame.append(Frame(MainWin,borderwidth=.5,relief=GROOVE))
         self.variable_Title_Frame[i].pack(side= LEFT,expand=YES)
         Label(self.variable_Title_Frame[i],text=i).pack(padx=1,pady=1)      
         self.Combo_Food_Select.append(StringVar())
         self.Combo_Food_stock.append(('Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Other'))
         self.Combo_Food_liste.append(Combobox(self.variable_Title_Frame[i], textvariable = self.Combo_Food_Select[i], \
            values = self.Combo_Food_stock[i], state = 'readonly'))
         self.Combo_Food_liste[i].bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.Position_Magnitude)
         self.Combo_Food_liste[i].pack()
    def Position_Magnitude(self, index):
        ##### Define for each kind the variety 
        for i in range (0, self.Nombr):

          if self.Combo_Food_liste[i].get() == 'Fruit':             
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[i]=(StringVar())
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[i]=(['Apple', 'Orange'])
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[i]=(Combobox(self.variable_Title_Frame[i], textvariable = self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[i], \
                                                values = self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[i], state = 'readonly'))
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[i].pack(side=BOTTOM)
          if self.Combo_Food_liste[i].get() == 'Vegetable':             
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[i]=(StringVar())
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[i]=(['Tomatoe', 'Pepper', 'Peas'])
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[i]=(Combobox(self.variable_Title_Frame[i], textvariable = self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[i], \
                                                values = self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[i], state = 'readonly'))
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[i].pack(side=BOTTOM)
          if self.Combo_Food_liste[i].get() == 'Other':
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[i]=(StringVar())
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry[i]=Entry(self.variable_Title_Frame[i], textvariable=self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[i], bg ='bisque', fg='maroon')
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[i].set("Specify")
             self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry[i].pack(side=BOTTOM)            
          if self.Combo_Food_liste[i].get() == "":
             next

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    MainWin = Tk()
    app = Postproc(MainWin, "Main Window") 
    MainWin.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda` function to send `i` to `Position_Magnitude()`

```
self.Combo_Food_liste[i].bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, index=i:self.Position_Magnitude(event,index))
```

In `Position_Magnitude` you can use `event.widget` in place of `self.Combo_Food_liste[i]`

```
from ttk    import *
from Tkinter import *



class Postproc:
    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        self.variable_Title_Frame = []
        self.variable_Title =[]
        self.Combo_Food_Select=[]
        self.Combo_Food_stock=[]
        self.Combo_Food_liste=[]
        self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select={}
        self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock={}
        self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste={}
        self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry={}
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title(title)
        self.parent.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.Closes)

        Frame1 = Frame(self.parent,borderwidth=.5,relief=GROOVE)
        Frame1.pack(side=LEFT,padx=1,pady=1)

        ### Define the number of packs then press 'Enter'
        self.variables_Title_number=IntVar()        
        self.Field_Ouputs = Entry(Frame1, textvariable=self.variables_Title_number, bg ='bisque', fg='maroon')
        self.Field_Ouputs.pack(side=LEFT,padx=1,pady=1)
        self.Field_Ouputs.bind("<Return>", self.Launch_Outputs)

    def Closes(self, event=None):
        self.parent.destroy()

    def Launch_Outputs(self, event=None):
        self.Nombr = self.variables_Title_number.get()
        self.Create_Outputs(self.Nombr)

    def Create_Outputs(self, Nombr):
        #### Define for each pack the kind of food
        for i in range(Nombr):            
             self.variable_Title_Frame.append(Frame(MainWin,borderwidth=.5,relief=GROOVE))
             self.variable_Title_Frame[i].pack(side= LEFT,expand=YES)

             Label(self.variable_Title_Frame[i],text=i).pack(padx=1,pady=1)      

             self.Combo_Food_Select.append(StringVar())
             self.Combo_Food_stock.append(('Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Other'))
             self.Combo_Food_liste.append(Combobox(self.variable_Title_Frame[i], textvariable = self.Combo_Food_Select[i], \
                values = self.Combo_Food_stock[i], state = 'readonly'))
             self.Combo_Food_liste[i].bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event, index=i:self.Position_Magnitude(event,index))
             self.Combo_Food_liste[i].pack()

    def Position_Magnitude(self, event, index):
        #print event.widget, index

        if event.widget.get() == 'Fruit':             
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index]=(StringVar())
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[index]=(['Apple', 'Orange'])
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index]=(Combobox(self.variable_Title_Frame[index], textvariable = self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index], \
                                            values = self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[index], state = 'readonly'))
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index].pack(side=BOTTOM)

        if event.widget.get() == 'Vegetable':             
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index]=(StringVar())
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[index]=(['Tomatoe', 'Pepper', 'Peas'])
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index]=(Combobox(self.variable_Title_Frame[index], textvariable = self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index], \
                                            values = self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[index], state = 'readonly'))
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index].pack(side=BOTTOM)

        if event.widget.get() == 'Other':
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index]=(StringVar())
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry[index]=Entry(self.variable_Title_Frame[index], textvariable=self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index], bg ='bisque', fg='maroon')
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index].set("Specify")
         self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry[index].pack(side=BOTTOM)            

        if event.widget.get() == "":
         next

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    MainWin = Tk()
    app = Postproc(MainWin, "Main Window") 
    MainWin.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

by the way: you will have to remove old combobox/entry if you select new thing in top combobox

```
def Position_Magnitude(self, event, index):
    #print event.widget, index

    try:
        if self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index]:
            self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index].pack_forget()
    except:
        pass

    try:
        if self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry[index]:
            self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry[index].pack_forget()          
    except:
        pass

    if event.widget.get() == 'Fruit':             
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index]=(StringVar())
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[index]=(['Apple', 'Orange'])
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index]=(Combobox(self.variable_Title_Frame[index], textvariable = self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index], \
                                        values = self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[index], state = 'readonly'))
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index].pack(side=BOTTOM)

    if event.widget.get() == 'Vegetable':             
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index]=(StringVar())
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[index]=(['Tomatoe', 'Pepper', 'Peas'])
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index]=(Combobox(self.variable_Title_Frame[index], textvariable = self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index], \
                                        values = self.Combo_Food_Pos_stock[index], state = 'readonly'))
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_liste[index].pack(side=BOTTOM)

    if event.widget.get() == 'Other':
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index]=(StringVar())
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry[index]=Entry(self.variable_Title_Frame[index], textvariable=self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index], bg ='bisque', fg='maroon')
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_Select[index].set("Specify")
     self.Combo_Food_Pos_Entry[index].pack(side=BOTTOM)            

    if event.widget.get() == "":
     next
```

Comment: It is exactly what I looked for, thank you very much, it is a very relevant answer!!